# PostgreSQL: Search by reference field value

Tags: postgresql

Currently, I have two tables named `users` and `posts`.  Ever `posts` row  includes a `userId` as reference and now I want to run query to search by `userId` array.

`select * from posts where 'userId' = ANY(ARRAY['9', '77']);`

And `posts` table looks like:

```
id     userId       text
1      9            text1
2      77           text2
```

The query returns empty while it returns full list if I remove `where` section. I guess the problem is that `userId` is a reference value but not sure how I can fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes denote string literals. `'userId'` is the `userId` **column**, but a string literal. Likewise, assuming you IDs are numbers, you should remove the quotes to get numeric literals instead of string literals:

```sql
select * from posts where userId = ANY(ARRAY[9, 77]);
-- No quotes -------------^----^-------------^--^^
```

Comment: It sounds reasonable but the problem is `userId` is recognized as `userid` if I remove the quotes, `column "userid" does not exist`

Comment: Use double quotes on the identifier if the identifier contains uppercase characters.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this works:

`select * from posts where userId in (9,77);`

Comment: I get `column "userid" does not exist` error.